# Creating new array vs modifing the same array in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Following is the piece of code which is working fine, but I have one doubt regarding - `const _detail = detail;` code inside a map method. Here you can see that I am iterating over an array and modifying the object and then setting it to `setState()`.

**Code Block -**

```
checkInvoiceData = (isUploaded, data) => {
    if (isUploaded) {
        const { invoiceData } = this.state;
        invoiceData.map(invoiceItem => {
            if (invoiceItem.number === data.savedNumber) {
                invoiceItem.details.map(detail => {
                    const _detail = detail;
                    if (_detail.tagNumber === data.tagNumber) {
                        _detail.id = data.id;
                    }
                    return _detail;
                });
            }
            return invoiceItem;
        });
        state.invoiceData = invoiceData;
    }
    this.setState(state);
};
```

Is this approach ok in `React` world or I should do something like -

```
const modifiedInvoiceData = invoiceData.map(invoiceItem => {
  ......
   code
  ......
})

this.setState({invoiceData: modifiedInvoiceData});
```

What is the pros and cons of each and which scenario do I need to keep in mind while taking either of one approach ?

Comment: A rule of thumb: Anytime you notice you are not using the return value of `map`, you are most liking doing something wrong. If you really don't need to use the return value, use `forEach`.

Comment: `state.invoiceData = invoiceData;` this is wrong in so many levels. One must not mutate state except using `setState`

Comment: Convention in React land is to make new copies of an array or object or really any data. This is especially important when you start using state management libs like Redux.

Comment: @ilkerkaran That says what, but not why.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mutate state, instead you can do something like this:

```
checkInvoiceData = (isUploaded, data) => {
  if (isUploaded) {
    this.setState({
      invoiceData: this.state.invoiceData.map(
        (invoiceItem) => {
          if (invoiceItem.number === data.savedNumber) {
            invoiceItem.details.map(
              (detail) =>
                detail.tagNumber === data.tagNumber
                  ? { ...detail, id: data.id } //copy detail and set id on copy
                  : detail //no change, return detail
            );
          }
          return invoiceItem;
        }
      ),
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something like this:

```js
checkInvoiceData = (isUploaded, data) => {
  // Return early
  if (!isUploaded) return

  const { invoiceData } = this.state;

  const updatedInvoices = invoiceData.map(invoiceItem => {
    if (invoiceItem.number !== data.savedNumber) return invoiceItem

    const details = invoiceItem.details.map(detail => {
      if (detail.tagNumber !== data.tagNumber) return detail

      return { ...detail, id: data.id };
    });

    return { ...invoiceItem, details };
  });

  this.setState({ invoiceData: updatedInvoices });
};
```

First, I would suggest returning early rather than nesting conditionals.

Second, make sure you're not mutating `state` directly (eg no `this.state = state`).

Third, pass the part of state you want to mutate, not the whole state object, to `setState`.

Fourth, return a new instance of the object so the object reference updates so React can detect the change of values.

I'm not saying this is the best way to do what you want, but it should point you in a better direction.